# Read file in Xcode project with Swift

Tags: ios, file, swift

I made a method to read a file from the temporary folder. I use the following lines to get the document's path:

```
path = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(folder)
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName + "." + fileType)
```

And it works great. My question is: how do I get the path for a file located in the main folders of the Xcode project? They are two text files that I drag and drop from a folder to the Xcode project. I selected the option "copy files if needed" when dropping the files. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is app's main bundle. You get a path of a file in it like this:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType:fileType) {
    // use path
}
```

Keep in mind this folder is read-only so you will need to copy the files to temp or documents folders if you want to make changes.

Comment: Thanks! I used this before but it didn't work, now it does :)

Answer (score 9):

Update the Swift 3.1 - Thanks @Filip Radelic

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType) {
    // use path
    print(path)
}
```

Comment: As an example, if you wanted to open a file called "file1.txt", then you'd call it like: `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file1", ofType: "txt") `

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4

```
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imagename.png", ofType: nil) {
           print("[check] FILE AVAILABLE \(path)")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) to get your main bundle, then `pathForResource(_ name: String?, ofType extension: String?) -> String?`.